# DataTable.Net modifying stateSave params?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I've got a situation where I am using the same Asp.Net MVC page to display a different data set based on some querystring values. i.e. `?isValid=true/false`

I am using **Datatables.net** to format the grid display. And I am using **serverSide** processing and **AJAX** to page thru the data. I am also using the `stateSave` parameter to hold column orders and search terms, etc..

As an example when I view the grid using one data set I get 10 pages. If I then select the 10th page to view and then go to the page using the other data set I may only have 5 pages but the `saveState` is set to page 10 so I get an empty grid because there are really only 5 pages of data.

I am trying to find a way to readjust the page value to one of the existing pages so that the grid will show something.

Is there a way to use jquery/javascript to set the page to a new value? Or even set it to be the first page by default?

I assume that this would go into the `drawCallback` event?

```
var table = $('#myTable');

table.dataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    scrollX: true,
    drawCallback: function(settings, json) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({ visibility: 'collapse' });
    },
    stateSave: true,
    stateLoadParams:function(settings,data){
        console.log("params",data);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DataTables `api` to check `page.info()` and alter the `start` page accordingly.

```
var table = $('#myTable');

table.dataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    scrollX: true,
    drawCallback: function(settings, json) {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({ visibility: 'collapse' });
    },
    stateSave: true,
    stateLoadParams:function(settings, data){
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
      var info = api.page.info();
      if (data.start > info.pages) {
        data.start = 1; // or (info.pages) for last page
      }
    }
};
```